Micro Service project structure around code sharing
I'm trying to move a monolith project structure to a micro services (self learning), and need directions on the the shared code placement.
src
|-- service1
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- Code
|   |-- DB
|
|-- service2
|   |-- Dockerfile
|   |-- Code
|   |-- DB
|
|-- utils  (only code) 
|   |-- code
|
|--docker-compose.yaml

Since all these services are on Python there are few pieces of code which are reused across. Here lets say utils is shared by both service1 and service2.
Few of the option I'm reading to manage the shared code is to create it as a separate package (pip or git) and add it as a dependency for each of the services, or using git-submodules.
But, my first target is to create a build system, with just one repo catering all the services with their dependencies. Trying to get to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo structure at first. And in this demo project the code is not shared, and where needed code is duplicated.
I'm playing around the build context in the docker-compose.yaml.
services:
  service1:
    build:
      context: ./service1/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

to
services:
  service1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./service1/Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

and updating the service1 Dockerfile to access utils, but it looks wrong to me.
Is there a way to build services along with utils as a dependency in the above structure ? Lets say copy the utils as a sibling to Code directory.
Any other options available to achieve this with out package manager or git-submodules ?
Any sample repo exploring this structure ?

If you're sharing code between micro services, you really have more of a distributed monolith. Which may or may not be an improvement on your simple monolith.

Agreed. I'm trying to explore around the packaging options, before I completely separate out the utils. Also utils is not a service on its own, its just a bunch of functions and constants heavily used by other services.

Well, that's the thing. If the services use those same constants and functions, then they're really part of one package. Micro services in the purest sense must be completely separate and only be connected by some sort of event bus. Because the main strength of micro services is that they can be updated completely independently, and make their own decisions about the best technology and structure to use. If you're sharing any code between them, those two premises are already broken. Now you just have a distributed monolith with extra headaches.

I've found a shared library to be useful for some core capabilities, but it should be a proper shared library (with its own versioning and release process and repository and compatibility-oriented testing).  A source-control system is not a dependency management tool and I'd avoid git submodules.  As @deceze suggests, in a container environment, very-tightly-couple services can be problematic: if you ever deploy in Kubernetes, you will routinely have multiple copies of both services, with multiple versions running at the same time during updates.

Thanks for the inputs. Got the monorepo setup and running using poetry, I can already see that the shared code expansion can be a challenging. Now will start on the separate private packaging for the shared code.
